# Connecting to Azure web socket server form C#

Tags: c#, azure, websocket

I have written a node server app which creates a web socket server.

I have also written a web page that creates a web socket client that connects to this server.

I can run the server locally and connect from my webpage JavaScript like so:

```
this.m_websocketConnection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3001');
```

all works fine.

I have published the node server app to my azure account (have enabled web sockets for the app) and I can just change the URL in the client JavaScript and everything still works fine (using an example URL for this post):

```
this.m_websocketConnection = new WebSocket('wss://mywebsocketapp.azurewebsites.net');
```

Now I want to write another client in a C# WinForms app.

I can do this using WebSocketSharp (https://sta.github.io/websocket-sharp/)

I can connect locally and all runs fine, here is the connection line:

```
m_websocketConnection = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3001");
```

(same local URL as in the JavaScript case)

However, if I just try the azure URL (as I successfully did in the JavaScript case) then the connection doesn't happen. I do not get the onOpen event firing:

```
m_websocketConnection = new WebSocket("wss://mywebsocketapp.azurewebsites.net");
```

Would anyone know what else I may need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Can you connect to the socket using Postman?

Comment: Yes. I had never tried this before. I downloaded postman. Made a new request, entered the URL (wss://mywebsocketapp.azurewebsites.net) and it connected, but still  no luck from my C# app.

Comment: Thanks to your answer a persevered. I tried WatsonWebsocket instead of WebSocketSharp  and now all is working.

Comment: @gnitsuk It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community.